# Slow performance for update cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I´m running this code to update my warehouse quantities based on the day before (yesterday). It works, but it is veeery slow.
Each day, the system generates around 50k+ rows, each one being for an address (position) on the warehouse. 
So, the cursor gets each address and then search for the quantity the day before, then updates.

Example:

Adress 01B134010 on 08/04/2019 had quantity 500

Adress 01B134010 on 09/04/2019 had quantity 450

So, when the code runs, it updates the column "DIF_DIA" with -50

Today, i´ve run the code and just for one brach (47k+ rows) it took more than 1 hour.

Is there a better/faster way to do it?

```
DECLARE @ARMAZEM    VARCHAR(2),
        @FILIAL     VARCHAR(3),
        @CLIENTE    VARCHAR(6),
        @GRPESTOQUE VARCHAR(6),
        @DATA       AS VARCHAR(8),
        @ENDERECO as VARCHAR(30),
        @DIFERENCA AS FLOAT

-- reinicia variaveis
SET @armazem = ''
SET @FILIAL = ''
SET @CLIENTE = ''
SET @GRPESTOQUE = ''
SET @DATA = ''
SET @ENDERECO = ''
SET @DIFERENCA = ''

DECLARE CUR_UPD_DIF_DIA CURSOR FOR
  SELECT CODIGO_ARMAZEM,
         CODIGO_FILIAL,
         CODIGO_CLIENTE,
         GRP_EST_COD,
         DATA_SALDO,
         CODIGO_ENDERECO
  FROM   WMS_OCUPACAO_ARMAZEM_DETALHE_V2_ESTATICO
  WHERE  DATA_SALDO >= '20190401'
  and CODIGO_FILIAL = '106'
         AND DIF_DIA IS NULL
  FOR UPDATE OF DIF_DIA

OPEN CUR_UPD_DIF_DIA

FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_UPD_DIF_DIA INTO @ARMAZEM,
                               @FILIAL,
                               @CLIENTE,
                               @GRPESTOQUE,
                               @DATA, 
                               @ENDERECO

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN

      -- pega a quantidade deste endereço ontem
      SELECT @DIFERENCA = IsNull(QUANTIDADE_PALLET,0)
      FROM   WMS_OCUPACAO_ARMAZEM_DETALHE_V2_ESTATICO T1
      WHERE  T1.DATA_SALDO = dateadd(day, -1 , @DATA)
             AND T1.GRP_EST_COD     = @GRPESTOQUE
             AND T1.CODIGO_CLIENTE  = @CLIENTE
             AND T1.CODIGO_ARMAZEM  = @ARMAZEM
             AND T1.CODIGO_ENDERECO = @ENDERECO
             AND T1.CODIGO_FILIAL   = @FILIAL

      -- e atualiza o endereço na data de hoje, tendo o valor da DIF_DIA a quantidade atual - a quantidade de ontem, assim, tem a diferença.
      -- se positivo, incrementou o endereço. Se negativo, diminuiu do endereço. Válido, na prática, somente para BLOCADO pois PP sempre terá apenas "1" de quantidade
      UPDATE WMS_OCUPACAO_ARMAZEM_DETALHE_V2_ESTATICO
      SET    DIF_DIA = (QUANTIDADE_PALLET - @DIFERENCA)
      WHERE  CURRENT OF CUR_UPD_DIF_DIA

      SET @DIFERENCA = 0

      FETCH NEXT FROM CUR_UPD_DIF_DIA INTO @ARMAZEM,
                                     @FILIAL,
                                     @CLIENTE,
                                     @GRPESTOQUE,
                                     @DATA, @ENDERECO
  END

CLOSE CUR_UPD_DIF_DIA

DEALLOCATE CUR_UPD_DIF_DIA
```

Comment: The way to speed up cursors is to eliminate cursors.  Your code does not need them.  But you should ask a different question which is "How do express this cursor as set-based operations?"  That question should include sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the code does.

Comment: you can you join query to update. can you please simplify your problem and add some data?

Comment: SQL isn't a programming language,so don't treat it like one; it's a query language. Don't think about what you want to do to a row, think about what you want to do to the (whole) column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set based approach will outperform a cursor like this orders of magnitude.

Based on your query, the set based approach could be something like this.
Disclaimer: the query is untested.

```
UPDATE WMS_OCUPACAO_ARMAZEM_DETALHE_V2_ESTATICO
SET    DIF_DIA = (QUANTIDADE_PALLET - (
    SELECT IsNull(QUANTIDADE_PALLET,0)
    FROM   WMS_OCUPACAO_ARMAZEM_DETALHE_V2_ESTATICO T1
    WHERE  T1.DATA_SALDO = dateadd(day, -1 , WMS_OCUPACAO_ARMAZEM_DETALHE_V2_ESTATICO.DATA_SALDO)
    AND    T1.GRP_EST_COD     = WMS_OCUPACAO_ARMAZEM_DETALHE_V2_ESTATICO.GRP_EST_COD
    AND    T1.CODIGO_CLIENTE  = WMS_OCUPACAO_ARMAZEM_DETALHE_V2_ESTATICO.CODIGO_CLIENTE
    AND    T1.CODIGO_ARMAZEM  = WMS_OCUPACAO_ARMAZEM_DETALHE_V2_ESTATICO.CODIGO_ARMAZEM
    AND    T1.CODIGO_ENDERECO = WMS_OCUPACAO_ARMAZEM_DETALHE_V2_ESTATICO.CODIGO_ENDERECO
    AND    T1.CODIGO_FILIAL   = WMS_OCUPACAO_ARMAZEM_DETALHE_V2_ESTATICO.CODIGO_FILIAL
))
WHERE  DATA_SALDO >= '20190401'
and CODIGO_FILIAL = '106'
AND DIF_DIA IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another option to optimize your UPDATE by doing a single operation instead of going Row-By-Agonizing-Row. Hopefully, I got the correct logic.

```
UPDATE atual
SET    DIF_DIA = atual.QUANTIDADE_PALLET - IsNull(ontem.QUANTIDADE_PALLET,0)
FROM WMS_OCUPACAO_ARMAZEM_DETALHE_V2_ESTATICO atual
LEFT
JOIN WMS_OCUPACAO_ARMAZEM_DETALHE_V2_ESTATICO ontem ON atual.DATA_SALDO      = dateadd(day, 1 , ontem.DATA_SALDO)
                                                    AND atual.GRP_EST_COD     = ontem.GRP_EST_COD    
                                                    AND atual.CODIGO_CLIENTE  = ontem.CODIGO_CLIENTE 
                                                    AND atual.CODIGO_ARMAZEM  = ontem.CODIGO_ARMAZEM 
                                                    AND atual.CODIGO_ENDERECO = ontem.CODIGO_ENDERECO
                                                    AND atual.CODIGO_FILIAL   = ontem.CODIGO_FILIAL  
WHERE atual.DATA_SALDO >= '20190401'
AND   atual.CODIGO_FILIAL = '106'
AND   atual.DIF_DIA IS NULL;
```

Comment: Speed-wise, this version (with JOIN) is faster than the other option with select?

Comment: I´m not sure, as I´m not able to test it. If it generates the same execution plan, both queries should be exchangeable and would depend on coding preferences.

Comment: No. However, it has the advantage that you can use multiple columns / expressions from the joined table. The version with the scalar subquery (that I posted) can only return one value.